# Перехват сообщений терминала Linux в Java

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, bash, terminal

Есть необходимость перехвата мониторинга терминала в Java-программе. Пробовал работать c `ProcessBuilder` - не получается.

Например, сохранить в файл результат при вызове команды `top`. Или, например, некая программа при выполнении команды просит ввести путь к файлу. В терминале это есть, а вот `ProcessBuilder` выводит только уже законченные ответы терминала.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вы пытаетесь решить не ту задачу, т.к. это немного не в духе Java, но вот пример решения:

```
import java.io.*;

public class JavaRunCommand {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String s = null;

        try {

            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -ef");

            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
                 InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
                 InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));


            System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }


            System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            System.exit(0);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("exception happened - here's what I know: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я бы так же сделал. Не знаю почему минусанули. Интересно выслушать.

Comment: Также как и в 'ProcessBuilder' не получается.
Приходит команда о соглашении с лицензией, на которую надо ответить  yes "Y", в терминале ее видно, а вот при использовании 'ProcessBuilder' и 'Runtime.getRuntime().exec()' просто процесс зависает